# How To Ensure Only One Brick is Fed Into a Lego Sorting Machine at a Time?

Tags: technic, building, motor, robotic, organisation

In [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=04JkdHEX3Yk), they create a machine that can take a bunch of legos put on to a conveyor belt and, using a camera, sort them into a number of categories. I am building a (smaller) version of this, and a problem I am running into is how to take the dozens of bricks from the conveyor belt and feed them into the sorter one at a time. The bricks are all different sizes and shape.

In the video, they use a vibrating sloped plate (seen at [1:49](https://youtu.be/04JkdHEX3Yk?t=1m49s)) to prevent bricks from being on top of each other.

However, I can’t seem to get the slope or vibration quite right, or get it stable enough so that it doesn’t fall apart.

Is there another way this can be done, or is there direction on how to do this anywhere?

Comment: Do you have any photos, videos or illustrations of what yo have built so far? It sounds like an good question and I would be interested to know more about your build so that we can help give an answer.